# When the function will be loaded into memory?

Tags: c, memory

For example, I am having a function:

```
void getA(char* outA) {
  char a[10000];
  // copy a to outA
}
```

Then I compile `getA` into a shared lib. and link with a executable.

I understand variable `a` stay in stack memory when `getA` be called.

When the function `getA` will be loaded into memory?

- when the executable start?
- when the `getA` be called?

Where the context of function will be allocated?

What if it's static linked, will be any different?

Comment: The *code* is probably loaded together with the rest of the program, when the OS loads it. The space for the variables are usually "allocated" (by manipulating the stack pointer) when the function is called.

Comment: Regarding static libraries, they are really only archives of object files, and linked like any other object file.

Comment: Handling (even the existence) of dynamic libraries is highly operating system specific, and within each OS there are different mechanisms. For example on Windows, you can [load DLLs at run time](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/using-run-time-dynamic-linking) via OS calls from your program, so there is no way to tell. Other details vary as well, like the treatment of "static" data in a "dynamic" library (if I have ever seen an oxymoron...). DLLs shared between programs (hey, that's the whole point, right?)  may already be in memory before your program was even coded...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The C standard does not concern itself with the loading of the code. It just needs to say how the program should behave when run.

In practice on modern operating systems there are many possibilities

- it is loaded into memory when the executable is started
- it is loaded into memory when called
- it is loaded into memory in somewhere between these 2 points
- it was loaded into memory *before* the executable started

The only difference between these cases are some minuscule timing differences in the program execution. You as a developer in most cases do not even need to know!

If you're running an executable from a removable device then it is not ok to unplug the device before asking the operating system if it is ok as it might not have loaded all of the program code into memory!

Comment: `it was loaded into memory before the executable started` When will this happen? When the program always stay in memory like whole OS and there don't have hard disk?

Comment: @Jiu for example if you've got *2* copies of the executable running. Then the function code will be loaded in ram, and will be mapped readily when it is executed

Comment: @Jui Another example is [`preload`](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/preload/) (and other, similar projects).

Comment: @Jiu `before the executable started` could be the case when the code lives in ROM. The code exists even when the power is shut off. And the allocation of automatic objects (such as the array `a[]`) is an implementation detail.